# codebase or code base?

Tags: compounds

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codebase

Which is the more canonized version?

canonized, not cannonized (although I'm certainly interested in anything that has been cannonized!)

Comment: English doesn't support the concept of "cannonized version" for such usages. In your specific case, [both are fairly common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+code+base%2Cthe+codebase&year_start=1990&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20code%20base%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20codebase%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: So give it your best shot.

Comment: Maybe the my usage of the word "cannonize" was incorrect. But we certainly say firetruck and not fire truck. so whatever the proper term is, firetruck is the "cannonized" version. I suppose "cannonized" effectively means whatever a professor will mark you down for, or whatever people will ridicule you for lol.

Comment: Well, lots of the "codebases" I've seen over the years deserved to be cannonized.

Comment: "canonical" is the word you are (were) looking for

Comment: @JasonS yes, thanks. that's the better word. I'll be a devil's advocate and say words only  become canonical only by going through canonization (omg stop this guy, he's making up even more words now). Basically, I'm sort of acknowledging the transition state this word is currently in by alluding to the verb, which takes something from being non canonical to canonical.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Anecdotally, I have only seen the spelling "codebase" while working as a computer programmer. However, it **is** a compound noun, so *codebase*, *code-base* and *code base* would all in principle be correct.  Codebase seems less ambiguous, however.

Comment: Ah! when all else is equal, and anti-ambiguity rears its head, it's a winning argument. I endorse `codebase` for this reason.